# Deploy libgdx to iPhone

Tags: iphone, libgdx

How to deploy libgdx powered application to iPhone or iPad? From the website it says deploying on iOS requires MonoTouch? Do i really need MonoTouch to deploy my app to iPhone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Wiki. It's explained there.

> The iOS backend currently uses MonoTouch/IKVM to run Java code on iOS. IKVM is used to 1) compile Java bytecode to .Net bytecode and 2) provide a runtime environment including much of the Java runtime library on top of the .Net runtime library. MonoTouch is used to compile the .Net bytecode to native code (ARM). This is a requirement by Apple in order for an application to be accepted on the app store. JIT compilers are currently not feasible on iOS. The code of an application has to be ahead of time cmpiled.

[Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP)
So yes you need it else you cant compile it to .NET if i get that right.